# How can I keep Tailoring?

Tags: rimworld

In RimWorld, I want to make "money" by tailoring, but I always need to click manually to someone do it. Can I priorize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh I figured out. I just need to priorize "Crafting".

Answer (score 2):

You can also set the bill to infinite, so they will constantly churn out clothing items.

For others reading the question: to prioritize, on the Overview screen, check 'Manual priorities' then lower the priority number of crafting for the colonist who you want to craft.

[image: [priorities screen]

Comment: Lower (as in, 1) or higher (as in, 4)? It amazes me that firefighting is 4 -I'd think firefighting takes priority over everything else, so 4 must be "highest priority"?

Comment: @Konerak 1 is the highest priority, 4 is the lowest. If multiple tasks have the same priority, the game prioritises them based on their default order left-right. In the picture, because everything is 4, firefighting is the highest priority. If cooking was changed to 3 on some colonists, they would cook before everything else.